# how to print a section of profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a configuration in application.yml:

```
chassis:
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      serializer: json
      cacheNullValues: true
```

I want to print the value of chassis.cache as:

```
type: redis
redis:
  serializer: json
  cacheNullValues: true
```

I used:

```
@Component
public class Operation1  {
    @Value("${chassis.cache}")
    private Object cacheConfig;
    ...
    public handle(){
        LOG.info("Cache config is: {}", cacheConfig.toString());
    }
}
```

and I got error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'Operation1': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'chassis.cache' in value \"${chassis.cache}\"","class":"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException","hash":"14cb5ff7"
```

Is it correct to do it this way? What was the catch?

Comment: Quick guess: The the value of `chassis.cache` is an object and not a string, but you decared the the variable as a string.

Comment: Since the configuration levels/items to print may change, it is preferable to be able to access it as json string. I tried change the type of the variable to Object and got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

You can get each property via `@Value` as a String. If you want to get the whole nested object, you can archive it via `@ConfigurationProperties`, here is example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("chassis.cache")
public class ChassisCacheProperties {
  private String type;
  private Redis redis;

  public static class Redis {
    private String serializer;
    private boolean cacheNullValues;
    // Setters & Getters
    // ToString
  }

  // Setters & Getters
  // ToString
}
```

Then `Autowire` it into any bean that you want to use: Example

```
@Component
public class Operation1 implements ApplicationRunner {

  private final ChassisCacheProperties chassisCacheProperties;

  public Operation1(ChassisCacheProperties chassisCacheProperties) {
    this.chassisCacheProperties = chassisCacheProperties;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("{}", chassisCacheProperties);
  }
}
```

Here is the output

```
ChassisCacheProperties(type=redis, redis=ChassisCacheProperties.Redis(serializer=json, cacheNullValues=true))
```

Comment: Thanks. however this is not flexible enough to print arbitrary configuration.

Comment: Alright then this is what r u looking for [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873185/how-to-read-multiple-properties-with-same-prefix-in-java-spring)